# Retrieve any User's ID with telebot

Tags: python, telegram

I want to make an administrator bot with python to telegram, and I working on a `function(chat_id, user_id)` that kick a user from the group, the syntax of the command is `/kick <username>`. Now, I don't know how can I get the `user_id` from the username argument.

I'm using the [telebot api](https://github.com/eternnoir/pyTelegramBotAPI)

```
@bot.message_handler(commands=['kick'])
def kick_user(message):
    user = ''.join(message.text.split(''.join(message.text.split()[0]), 1)[1])
    resp = self.bot.kick_chat_member(chat_id=message.chat.id, user_id=None)
```